# Conditional Loop for Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been having a little trouble with my code, and I don't really know what the next step is. I'd appreciate any help!.

basically, if status = single or divorced, I add the key and values to my new_dictionary. If status = married for that key, I have to check if within that key (ex: PEP500), type B's start and stop values compared to type A's start and stop values of the same key fit my condition in order to add it to my dictionary.

```
mydict = {
    'PEP300': [
        {
            'start': '800', 
            'stop': '1000', 
            'type': 'A', 
            'status': 'single'
        },
        {
            'start': '300', 
            'stop': '200', 
            'type': 'B', 
            'status': 'divorced'
        },
        {
            'start': '400', 
            'stop': '200', 
            'type': 'B', 
            'status': 'divorced'
        }
    ],
    'PEP400': [
        {
            'start': '600', 
            'stop': '400', 
            'type': 'A', 
            'status': 'single'
        },
        {
            'start': '600', 
            'stop': '300', 
            'type': 'B', 
            'status': 'divorced'
        },
        {
            'start': '700', 
            'stop': '200', 
            'type': 'B', 
            'status': 'divorced'
            }
    ],
    'PEP500': [
        {
            'start': '600', 
            'stop': '800', 
            'type': 'A', 
            'status': 'single'
        },
        {
            'start': '400', 
            'stop': '500', 
            'type': 'B', 
            'status': 'married'
        },
        {
            'start': '300', 
            'stop': '700', 
            'type': 'B', 
            'status': 'married'
        }
    ]
}
```

What I have tried:

```
start_B = [mydict[pep]["start"] 
                 for pep in mydict.keys() 
                 if [mydict[pep]['status'] == "married"] and [mydict[pep]['type'] == "B"]

start_A = [mydict[pep]["start"] 
                 for pep in mydict.keys() 
                 if [mydict[pep]['status'] == "single"] and [mydict[pep]['type'] == "A"]

stop_B = [mydict[pep]["stop"] 
                 for pep in mydict.keys() 
                 if [mydict[pep]['status'] == "married"] and [mydict[pep]['type'] == "B"]

stop_A = [mydict[pep]["stop"] 
                 for pep in mydict.keys() 
                 if [mydict[pep]['status'] == "single"] and [mydict[pep]['type'] == "A"]

new_dictionary = {}

for pep in mydict.keys():
    if ([mydict[pep]['status'] == 'single']
    or [mydict[pep]['status'] == 'divorced'])
    if [mydict[pep]['status'] == 'married'] and (start_B < start_A and start_A < stop_B and stop_B < stop_A):
        new_dictionary.update({pep:mydict[pep]})
```

Expected outcome: since one of the dictionaries in PEP500 doesn't meet my conditions (400<600 but 500 is not > 600) it is not added to the dictionary.

```
new_dictionary = {'PEP300': [{'start': '800',
                     'stop': '1000',
                     'type': 'A',
                     'status': 'single'},
                    {'start': '300',
                     'stop': '200',
                     'type: 'B',
                     'status': 'divorced'},
                    {'start': '400',
                     'stop': '200',
                     'type: 'B',
                     'status': 'divorced'}],
          'PEP400': [{'start': '600',
                     'stop': '400',
                     'type': 'A',
                     'status': 'single'},
                    {'start': '600',
                     'stop': '300',
                     'type': 'B',
                     'status': 'divorced'},
                    {'start': '700',
                     'stop': '200',
                     'type: 'B',
                     'status': 'divorced'}],
          'PEP500': [{'start': '600',
                     'stop': '800',
                     'type': 'A'}
                     'status': 'single',
                    {'start': '300',
                     'stop': '700',
                     'type: 'B',
                     'status': 'married'}]}
```

Comment: why " 'type " has single " ' "

Comment: Your `mydict` has multiple typos, fixe it.

Comment: i fixed typos in `mydict`.

Comment: thanks :)  @moctarjello

Comment: So what are you trying to do at the last `for-loop` ? I have already solved the code above(`start_A`, `start_B`, etc)

Comment: Oh wow thanks a lot! for the for loop this is what I am trying to do:                             
if status = single or divorced, I add the key and values to my new_dictionary. 

If status = married for that key, I have to check if within that key (ex: PEP500), type B's start and stop values compared to type A's start and stop values of the same key fit my condition in order to add it to my dictionary.

Comment: i just saw your comment.. ok let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've worked on your problem.. and there are more clarifications to it that you should provide. For example, are you aware that you are comparing `list`s when you do `start_B < start_A` ?

For now i guess this could help:

```
start_B = [
        mydict[pep][i]["start"] 
            for pep in mydict.keys()
                for i, spouse in enumerate(mydict[pep])
                    if spouse['status'] == "married"
                    and spouse['type'] == "B"
        ]

start_A = [
        mydict[pep][i]["start"] 
            for pep in mydict.keys()
                for i, spouse in enumerate(mydict[pep])
                    if spouse['status'] == "single"
                    and spouse['type'] == "A"
        ]

stop_B = [
        mydict[pep][i]["stop"] 
            for pep in mydict.keys()
                for i, spouse in enumerate(mydict[pep])
                    if spouse['status'] == "married"
                    and spouse['type'] == "B"
        ]

stop_A = [
        mydict[pep][i]["stop"] 
            for pep in mydict.keys()
                for i, spouse in enumerate(mydict[pep])
                    if spouse['status'] == "single"
                    and spouse['type'] == "A"
        ]


new_dictionary = {}

for pep, spouses in mydict.items():
    new_values = [spouse for spouse in spouses \
                    if spouse['status'] == 'single' \
                    or spouse['status'] == 'divorced' \
                    or (spouse['status'] == 'married'
                        and start_B < start_A 
                        and start_A < stop_B 
                        and stop_B < stop_A)]
    new_dictionary.update({pep:new_values})
```

You can comment for any clarifications and we will work on from there..

Comment: I just saw this! That's exactly what I was trying to do, and it works. Thank you so much for taking the time to help, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @annavrin if it solved your problem you can mark it as "solved" and "upvote" so it can simplify other people's search